# several react apps with express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

The idea is to make a lot of separate react apps on the one express server, so each of them should appear using the url something like `mysite.com/app1`, `mysite.com/app2` etc

my express code:

```
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public'))); // just a simple html, not a react
app.use('/app1',express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/build-1'))); // react
app.use('/app2',express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/build-2'))); // react

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/app1/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/build-1', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/app2/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/build-2', 'index.html'));
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

so, actually this works

but there's a problem - when visiting the root url of the site - `mysite.com` - I get the ordinary `index.html` file, not a react one, **as expected**, but using the path - `mysite.com/app1` or `mysite.com/app2` - the url changes to just `mysite.com` and *the app1 or app2* launches from the root of the site, not staying on the route `mysite.com/app1` or `mysite.com/app2`

and yep, I did configure the react's package.json file for both of the apps

```
{"homepage": "http://localhost:3000/app1"}
```

and

```
{"homepage": "http://localhost:3000/app2"}
```

**the problem has been found**: the route I configured in the React App rewrote the url path to the root, so that's why the bug occured

Comment: Did you started your react apps with the create-react-app package? Or did you started them another way. I'm sure on the frontend your apps are redirecting to the root path.
One way to overcome this would be to set a `<base href="/appX" />` within the head tag of each app. if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I did start it with the create-react-app package. I do believe it is something to do with redirecting. Unfortunately, `<base href="/app1" />` or `<base href="/app2" />` didn't work

Comment: If you could share your code or construct a sample via something like codesandbox.io we could understand more details about what can be causing this issue. It is not a generic case and we must have a sample to work into.